# font embed not working

Tags: html, css, fonts, embed

i am trying to embed font "gothamcondensed" on my website but its not working, i used @font-face from font-squirrel. i just moved my fonts on server and change the url but its not working.

any suggestions guys? I really need an advice please. below is my code:

```
    @font-face { 
    font-family: 'gothamcondensedbold';
    src: url('http://some-url.com/zts-fonts/gothamcondensed-bold_0-webfont.eot');
    src: url('http://nx3corp.com/zts-fonts/gothamcondensed-bold_0-webfont.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
         url('http://nx3corp.com/zts-fonts/gothamcondensed-bold_0-webfont.woff2') format('woff2'),
         url('http://nx3corp.com/zts-fonts/gothamcondensed-bold_0-webfont.woff') format('woff'),
         url('http://nx3corp.com/zts-fonts/gothamcondensed-bold_0-webfont.ttf') format('truetype'),
         url('http://nx3corp.com/zts-fonts/gothamcondensed-bold_0-webfont.svg#gothamcondensedbold') format('svg');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;

}    body {
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    font-family: 'gothamcondensedbold';
}
```

Comment: is the `http://some-url.com` correct for the first eot? or is that just an example placeholder

Comment: are you getting an error in the console? Something like `No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin'`

Comment: yes the url is correct i am able to download the font from url

Comment: yes i am getting below message in console:

Font from origin 'http://some-url.com' has been blocked from loading by Cross-Origin Resource Sharing policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'null' is therefore not allowed access.

Comment: Don't forget to mark as resolved, either by yourself or from the answer if it helped solve your issue.

Answer (score 0):

The problem seems to be with the cross domain font request. You may want to look at placing this into the .htaccess or httpd.conf file on the server:

```
# Apache config
<FilesMatch ".(eot|ttf|otf|woff)">
    Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
</FilesMatch>

# nginx config
if ($filename ~* ^.*?\.(eot)|(ttf)|(woff)$){
    add_header Access-Control-Allow-Origin *;
}
```

for further info check here: http://davidwalsh.name/cdn-fonts

Or upload the fonts to the same server of course if that is an option!

Comment: Thanks very much guys, that was actually cross origin issue i uploaded the fonts on same server and it works. :)
thanks lee_gladding

Comment: haha... didn't realise that was an option for you, but glad we got the root of your problem.